# Is it possible to call a contract function just by making a transction to a address

Tags: ethereum

Currently I'm trying to learn ethereum and smart contract. I read this tutorial: [Dapps for beginners](https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/your-first-dapp/)
I'm just wondering now, if I have to call everytime a function from a contract (as in the tutorial above) or is it possible that a specific function is executed when I just transfer some ethereum to that contract address?

Example: 
I execute the code below, and the receiver address is also a address with a contract. One specific function should now be executed at the receiver function.

eth.sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount})

Comment: You will probably find an answer at [ethereum stack exchange](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/), first try to understand [the difference of a call and a transaction](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/765/87) and then read about the usage of [the ABI for communicating with contracts](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/234/87). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a nameless payable function in your smart contract.

This will then be the default function to execute if someone sends a raw transaction at your contract's address.

```
function() payable public {

}
```

Also, the other answer here states that you need to know the contract ABI to communicate with contracts but **this is not true.**

You need to know the contract address, the function name and the input and output parameter types. *(You could use [Web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods)'s method.call or method.sendTransaction to send the encoded data in the transaction object and interact with the contract.)*

The ABI may have this information, but the ABI is not required itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can only communicate with contracts if you know the ABI which is the *application binary interface*.

In general, an ABI is the interface between two program modules, one of which is often at the level of machine code. The interface is the de facto method for encoding/decoding data into/out of the machine code. In ethereum, it's basicly how you can encode solidity contracts for the EVM and backwards how to read the data out of transactions.

If you have the JSON ABI of a contract, you still have to decide if you want to make calls or transactions. The difference between a call and a transaction is the following:

- Transactions are created by your client, signed and broadcasted to the network. They will eventually alter the state of the blockchain, e.g., by manipulating balances or values in smart contracts.
- Calls are only executed locally on your computer and not broadcasted to the network, e.g., a *dry run*.

Calls are usefull for debugging smart contracts as they do not cost transaction fees or gas.

So if you only send a transaction to a contract without using any interface, you wont be able to execute any code on the contract.